# Is `usize`-indexing in Rust inefficient on some architectures?

Tags: pointers, rust, indexing, types

On some architectures, the pointer size can be larger than the size of the default data type. Consequently, being forced to use a `usize` in Rust might result in inefficiencies.

For example, on an 8 bit AVR-architecture we might have a pointer length of 16 bit. With arrays shorter than 256 entries, we'd have to carry out expensive 16 bit operations on the index, although single-cycle 8 bit would be sufficient.

Is this correct? If so, is there a way to enforce a smaller `usize` in such situations? Or does the compiler take care for this automatically?

Possibly related questions and issues:

- [What is the correct type to use for an array index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230697/what-is-the-correct-type-to-use-for-an-array-index)
- https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1748

Comment: you can't control usize size manually no, if your arch have 16 bit pointer you WANT 16 bit usize. You can use u8 and cast to usize if you wish that should always be correct. Thus any overflow is your responsibility.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is unrelated to casting. I'll try to be more specific: consider a for-loop like this `for(uint8_t i = 1; i < 100; i++) {#access array[i]}` in C. The add-operation `i++` requires exactly one clock cycle on an 8 bit AVR micro controller. On the other hand, `i++` requires three or more instructions if `i` is specified as 16 bit because it will be implemented as two 8 bit operations and a shift. Hence, I certainly do not want my index to be 16 bit if it doesn't have to be. How does Rust handle this?

Comment: and what you ask here is very explain in answer of the duplicate. The accepted answer show an example of how use a u8 as index, and the second answer show that there is an possible overhead. That not because you don't like the answer that the answer is wrong. You may ask "Is it possible to use an u8 to index a pointer in Rust" in another question, thus I don't think it's possible.

Comment: No, sorry again. You're right. If I have to do some number crunching on my index before I use it to access the array entry, I do that as `u8` or whatever. But as soon as I access the array, it has to be a `usize`. I get it. Thanks!!